# How to assign a value from chrome.storage to a variable for extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, scope, google-chrome-storage

So I am making a chrome extension game. I have a highscore variable that I want to store with `chrome.storage`.

In the background.js, I have :

```js
chrome.storage.sync.set({"highScore": 0});
```

and in the popup.js, I have :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
 
    let highScore;
    
    chrome.storage.sync.get('highScore', (result) => {
        highScore = result.highScore;
        console.log(highScore); // here it is 0
    })

    console.log(highScore); // here it is undefined

});
```

> why ?

Is there a way to do what I want to do ?